# Why does PHP throw a 404 error after running for 180 seconds?

Tags: php, browser, http-status-code-404, session-timeout

I have a PHP script, which works fine. Sometimes, it needs to run for longer than 30 seconds, so I have increased the max_execution_time to 6000.

The problem I now have is that for long queries (longer than three minutes), I get a 404 error.

I know that script is working, as I can see changes in the files that I am updating, but it does not complete.

I think (but not sure) that the web page does not get a response (as the script is still running and despite doing echo's they are not reflected yet).

I am not that savvy when it comes to tracking these type of problems down but trying to google this issue, I read that the network tab might be useful to look at.

Not sure if the following screen shots are useful, but thought they might be.

[image: Inspect: Network/Timing]

[image: Inspect: Network/Response]

[image: Inspect: Network/Headers]

Wonder if anybody can help?

I am running Google Chrome (Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit)), but have also tried on Brave, with the same result.

Comment: Been carrying out further investigations. It appears that the PHP script continues to run (and completes), but returns a 404, I assume after hitting some time limit. This means that the PHP echo statements are not displayed.

I am writing details to a trace files, and the files are updated as planned, but I would still prefer to see the echo statements when the script actually completes.

Comment: Still not managed to solve this. I think my next course of action is to try and use PHP on a command line when logged onto the server. Not sure how to do this (but I'll work it out). I'll let you know. I am hoping that the time limit is due to the web page and I will not hit the same limits if running directly on the server.